# Git - Android Studio is not visually showing any branches

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I was minding my business then suddenly Android studio crashed and when I re-opened it, it left me with this (all my branches disappeared visually):

[image]

Then I checked if my `branches` still exist using the terminal, turns out, it still does:

[image]

**Question:** How do I restore the `GUI` for branches back?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `project's .idea` folder is messed up. So, try to regenerate it.

1. Close `Android studio`
2. Go to your project directory using `command prompt` or `windows GUI`
3. Delete `.idea` folder
4. `Reopen` your project with `Android studio` (`.idea` would re-generate now)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issues like that:

1- Delete the .idea file

2- Go to File -> Invalidate cache/restart -> Just restart.

Ready!

P.data: Android Studio 4.1.1